# My Samsung Galaxy Note10+ is automatically deleting my Music!

Tags: samsung, music, delete

In Some days, I listen to music on my Samsung music app. today, I found out that some of my music is gone! Even deleted on the My Files app! is there anything I can do to stop this?

Most of my music is from "internal storage/Music"
Some of my music is from "SD Card/Music"
All of my music is from "Onedrive/Music"
Only "sdcard/music" are having missing files
It happens whenever i favorite a song using Samsung music